# How to work with Async/Await in expressjs router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, mongoose

I've been battling with an issue concerning Async/Await, I'm relatively new to Nodejs. I have a repository where I connect directly to my mongodb collection to retrieve some data it but when I connect my controller to this repository, I get a nulled response.
Please checkout my code below:-

**SyncRepository.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

exports.ItemRepo = async (limit) => {
  try {
     await mongoose.connection.db.collection('items_1087342')
        .find({}, {timeout: false}).limit(limit).toArray((err, results) => {
            // results.forEach(e => {
            //     console.log(e.item_id);
            // }); //This works well
            return results;
        });
 } catch (e) {
    throw Error('Error Loading Data:- ' + e.message);
 }
};
```

**SyncController.js**

```
const syncRepo = require('../../../Repositories/Sync/SyncRepository');

exports.getItem = async (req, res) => {
  try {
     await syncRepo.ItemRepo(7)
        .then(element => {
            console.log(element);
           return res.json(element); //This return null
        });
    // return await res.json(await syncRepo.ItemRepo(7));
 } catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).json({ status: 400, message: e.message });
 }
};
```

Comment: `ItemRepo` returns nothing. also don't mix `await` with `.then`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing `async/await` and traditional Promise syntax. Try this :

SyncRepository.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

exports.ItemRepo = limit => {
     return mongoose.connection.db.collection('items_1087342')
        .find({}, {timeout: false})
        .limit(limit)
        .exec() // see @Enslev's explanation in the comments
};
```

SyncController.js

```
const syncRepo = require('../../../Repositories/Sync/SyncRepository');

exports.getItem = async (req, res) => {
  try {
     let element = await syncRepo.ItemRepo(7)
     return res.json(element);
 } catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).json({ status: 400, message: e.message });
 }
};
```

Comment: `try/catch` around a Promise?

Comment: [Queries does not not return a promise by themselves in mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html). You need to add `.exec()` after `.limit()` for that to happen. Right now the controller is awaiting a sync function.

Comment: I get your point, but I have some code in production that `return Model.select(...).limit(...).lean()` and it works perfectly, I don't need to add `.exec()`

Comment: Sure, it *works*, but it is running synchronously and halting the thread. You can `await` a synchronous function no problem, but that does not make it asynchronous. It does not take advantage of the event loop without `.exec()`

Comment: What, really?? Wow, I had no idea. Thanks for the explanation, I'll use that from now on

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks for the answer but with the above code I get `Converting circular structure to JSON` and when I add `.lean()` I get this error `mongoose.connection.db.collection(...).find(...).lean is not a function` what can I do in this instance?

Comment: And I get `mongoose.connection.db.collection(...).find(...).limit(...).exec is not a function` when I add `.exec`

Comment: To be honest, you really should add some [Mongoose models](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html). It is very bad practice to call the `db.collection` like that every time you make a request. Once you add the models, you will find that functions exist.